# Evaluating file properties and API responses in Chai assertions

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai

This is my first time using Chai. I want to write tests that will upload a file and look at the responses. I suspect my code below is close but there might be details I'm not aware of.

1. Is my file being dynamically created correctly?
2. How do I extract the filename from `testfile`?
3. Am I correctly attaching the file to the Request global?

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const COUNT_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/fileUpload';

// mock file
class MockFile {
    constructor ({ name = 'file.txt', size = 1024, type = 'plain/txt', lastModified = new Date() }) { }
    create (name, size, mimeType) {
        const blob = new Blob([ 'a'.repeat(size) ], { type });
        blob.lastModifiedDate = lastModified;
        return new Blob([ blob ], name);
    }
}

describe('file-upload-api', () => {
    // mock file test harness
    describe('Mock file for file upload testing', () => {
        const testfile = new MockFile({
            type: 'image/png',
            size: 50000,
            name: 'helloworld.txt',
        });

        it('testfile should be defined', () => {
            expect(testfile).to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(testfile.name).to.equal('helloworld.txt');
            expect(testfile.size).to.equal(50000);
        });

        it('should return 200 when a valid file is uploaded', async () => {
            const request = new Request(COUNT_API_URL, { method: 'POST', body: { files: [ testfile ] } });
            return await fetch(request)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    expect(data).to.eql({ message: 'request.file.originalname: helloworld.txt' });
                });
        });

        it('should return 400 when a null file is uploaded', async () => {
            const request = new Request(COUNT_API_URL, { method: 'POST', body: { files: [] } });
            return await fetch(request)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    expect(data).to.eql({ message: 'Please upload a file' });
                });
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: The constructor of your `MockFile` does not store any of the arguments. That's why your first test is failing. Also the `.create()` method shouldn't need to take those options again, and you should actually call the method.

Comment: Your test descriptions sounds like the tests are looking for some HTTP status codes, but they actually don't test for that.